# Obtaining data from Spotify Top Charts using spotifyr

Tags: r, loops, spotify

I'm trying to obtain the audio features for the top 200 charts of all of 2017 using the spotifyr package on R, I tried:

```
days<- spotifycharts::chartdaily()
for (i in days) {
    spotifycharts::chart_top200_daily(region = "global",days = "days[i]")
  }
```

to obtain the top 200 daily for all of 2017, but I was unable to do it. 
Can someone help me? :(

Comment: You have days within quotes. Try removing the quotes: 
chart_top200_daily(region = "global", days = days[i])

Comment: Tried that, but did not work... I'm trying to make a loop to obtain the entire year of top 200 daily

Answer (score 0):

It works, if you turn days from `tibble` into vector:

```
days <- unlist(chart_daily())

lapply(days[1:3], function(i) chart_top200_daily("global", days = i))
```

But it parse data badly, so there will be problems with variable names, etc:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     x1 x2                 x3      note.that.these.figures.are.generated.… x5                 
  <int> <chr>              <chr>                                     <int> <chr>              
1    NA Track Name         Artist                                       NA URL                
2     1 thank u, next      Ariana…                                 8293841 https://open.spoti…
3     2 Taki Taki (with S… DJ Sna…                                 5467625 https://open.spoti…
4     3 MIA (feat. Drake)  Bad Bu…                                 3955367 https://open.spoti…
5     4 Happier            Marshm…                                 3357435 https://open.spoti…
6     5 BAD                XXXTEN…                                 3131745 https://open.spoti…
```